# Is 〜てある commonly used with verbs other than 書く?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, verbs, subsidiary-verbs

This question is prompted by @Abi's comment　on [meanings of 「書{か}いてある」 and 「書かれている」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18473/):

> 書いてある seems to be commonly used, while with other verbs 〜てある is not so common, right?

And indeed, I don't really recall seeing `〜てある` with other verbs. So what are other common verbs used with it?

[Stative verbs: ～ている　vs　～てある　vs　～（ら）れる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5505/) mentions an example of `窓が開けてある` but I feel it's somewhat less natural than e.g.  `開けておく` or `開けっ放し`.

Comment: 置いてある is the only one that springs to mind...

Comment: （料理を）作ってある，とか，（切符を）買ってある，とか，（宿題を）してある，とか，（住所を）控えてある，とか，（鍵を）かけてあるとか…まで書いて気がついたけどちょっと違う用例の話みたいですね．「柿がそこに吊ってある/干してある」とか「旗が挿してある/掲げてある/飾ってある」とかは？

Answer (score 1):

(From comment)

Although it may be a bit grammatically different from 書いてある, examples are:

- （料理を）作ってある
- （切符を）買ってある
- （宿題を）してある
- （住所を）控えてある
- （鍵を）か‌​けてある

Other candidates are

> 柿がそ‌​こに吊ってある/干してある
>
> 旗が挿‌​してある/掲げてある/飾ってある

Comment: How are they "grammatically different"?