# how do I use と書くいてありました in different tempus

Tags: grammar, particle-と

I'm struggling to learn how to use と書くいてありました in citing from things I have read and learn to quote it in the japanese way. the way I use 書くいて is apparently in the wrong tempus so is it okay to use either 書くありました or　書きありました?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 書**く**いてありました is incorrect. You misspelled 書いてありました, no?

Comment: What does "tempus" mean?

Comment: Related: [Stative verbs: ～ている　vs　～てある　vs　～（ら）れる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5505/stative-verbs-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b-vs-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%a6%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b-vs-%ef%bd%9e-%e3%82%89-%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b) AND [meanings of 「書いてある」 and 「書かれている」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18473/meanings-of-%e6%9b%b8%e3%81%8b%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b-and-%e6%9b%b8%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b).